# Spring Security login with Ajax and success handler

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am working on letting user login to system using Ajax and with help of Spring security,As of now everything is working fine and as expected.
On Successful authentication, I am calling a `SuccessHandler` to do some post authentication work.

I need to pass some information (OK status or something like ) back to the calling method in my JSP page so as I can do other work in my JSP page.
One option is to add following code in `onAuthenticationSuccess` method

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request,final
HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication) throws 
IOException, ServletException {

 // work done
try{
   response.getWriter().print("SUCCESS");//return "SUCCESS" string
   response.getWriter().flush();
}
catch(IOException e){
}
```

}
Though that will do work, but is there any other way or alternate to do it in good way or this approach is good enough?

Comment: i am interested to know..in what case you would need this?

Comment: @dhamibirendra: Need to check that `onAuthenticationSuccess` is able to do all work which it was suppose to do

Comment: seems, you are doing it in most desired way